# Slow down Laravel worker

Tags: laravel, redis, queue

I have hooked up Redis with Laravel for queuing emails and all is fine...
but in dev environment I use mailtrap.io (free version).

And the problem is that mailtrap allows to receive only 2 emails per second, so I never get all the emails that are queued, because redis sends emails like crazy... maybe 10 per/s

Is there a way somehow to slow down the queue so that it sends max 2 mails per second?

Comment: Maybe something like `Mail::getSwiftMailer()->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(2, 1));` The first param is max number of emails to send per connection, the second parameter is the wait time, in seconds, between connections. For more help [check this](http://www.camroncade.com/limit-the-number-of-messages-sent-on-one-smtp-connection-laravel-5/)

Comment: I am using Laravel - Notifications to send mails...

Comment: Can you help me a little bit, where exactly to call this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It is a solution and they're called jobs :) 
you can create a file to send emails exclusively in the Jobs Folder and a class like this

```
class SendPushNotification extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $pushNotification;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(PushNotification $pushNotification)
    {
        $this->pushNotification = $pushNotification;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->pushNotification->send();
    }
}
```

And then call the class in the controller

`$this->dispatch(new SendPushNotification($pushNotification))->delay(1);`

Delay is for seconds you can create a constructor with an array to receive two emails o many you want maybe some var than can be changed by the .env to change the number of emails per second